# Proving a function takes in the unit disk every complex number c in the unit disk exactly n times

Tags: complex-analysis

Let us consider the conformal mapping：

$$B(z) = e^{i\theta} \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{z-a_k}{1- \bar a_k z} $$
We wish to prove that $B$ takes in the unit disk $D$ every complex number $c$ with $|c| < 1$ exactly $n$ times.

$a_k$ are complex numbers in the unit disk D, there are overall $a_1, a_2, ... a_n$ numbers.

Now I'm a bit confused about how does the statement mean. It seems that $B(z) = c$ has $n$ solutions to me, but I don't know whether this interpretation is correct.

If so, how to prove it? It's not hard to see B maps D into D. And I suspect surjectivity plays a role here.

Comment: What are those $a_k$? Are they related in any way with $a$?

Comment: @ajotatxe sorry for the confusion. Hope it is clear now!

Comment: The equation $B(z)=c$ is polynomial of degree exactly $n$ after getting rid of denominator, so has $n$ roots including multiplicity; show that $B$ sends unit disc to itself and exterior to exterior and conclude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the hint mentioned in the comment I can now provide a proof.

The meaning of the question is: B(z) = c has exactly n solutions inside the unit disk D for $|c| \lt 1$.

We first inspect all z in D. The first step is to prove $|B(z)|  \lt 1$. Note that all $ |a_k| \lt 1$, and $|z-a|^2 = (z - a) (\bar z - \bar a)$; $|1-\bar az|^2 = (1 - \bar az)(1-a \bar z)$. Compare their values and we can see $|B(z)| < 1$ as $|z| \lt 1$. (i)

On the contrary, for $|z| \gt 1$ we have $|B(z)| > 1$, hence there is no solution outside the unit disk. (ii)

Combine (i) and (ii), and observe that B(z) is a polynomial of degree n, B(z) = c will yield exactly n solutions on the complex plane by **Fundamental Theorem of Algebra**, we know that they must all inside the unit disk.